# Boostrap filter table control isn't working even with CDN on ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I wanna be able to filter a column in a table using bootstrap, this is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/filter-control/utils.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <table class="table table-hover" data-search="true" data-filter-control="true">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="align-middle" data-filter-control="input" data-filter-control-visible="true">Example Column</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var example in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@atividade.Example</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Why doesn't work?

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you use F12 developer Console tool to check your page, you might see this issue:

[image]

The issue is related the `bootstrap-table.min.js` reference, you didn't add it in your web page. Try to change your code as below:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/filter-control/utils.min.js"></script>
```

The sample code as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication6.Models.UserViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserIndex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.18.3/extensions/filter-control/utils.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">    
    <table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-search="true"
           data-filter-control="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="firstName" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">FirstName</th>
                <th data-field="lastName" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">LastName</th>
                <th data-field="email" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Email</th>
                <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]